# Windows 8.1 (Blue) SkyDrive folder appearing after deletion though turned it's off

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, onedrive

I had Windows 8 installed on my laptop and SkyDrive folder on a local drive. But I needed to update to Windows 8.1 Pro edition, wich I did. After that SkyDrive screw my files up because of this integration into OS. I was very dissapointed and decided to remove it. Than I discovered that it's not possible, so I followed these steps [How to disable SkyDrive integration on Windows 8.1](http://pureinfotech.com/2013/07/09/disable-skydrive-windows-8-1/) completely. But after reboot I have SkyDrive folder appearing once again (empty).

How can I make the madness stop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The folder is appearing where?  Why not just delete the folder?

Comment: I delete it, but the folder is recreated when I reboot the computer

Answer (score 0):

When you remove skydrive from your pc it will stay there but only as a local folder.

Just select it and hit delete. Shut down properly (or restart) and your issue will be resolved.

Comment: doesn't work, I deleted it countless times and after that rebooted my laptop... no effect